# being faced with a serious problem

Tags: grammar

*Today, we are being faced with a serious problem.*

Is the above sentence possible in English? I think that the sentence "the car is being repaired" is OK but in the case of the sentence with the verb "face" I am not sure.

Comment: You can say "Today , I am being faced by a serious  problem (passive voice of Today, a serious problem is facing me).  However,  you usually say Today, I am faced with a serious problem. Here, you have used "faced" as a participle adjective.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK as long as "a serious problem" is an ongoing situation, such as global warming or overpopulation.
It is more broad than phrases like "dealing with" or taking care of", and addresses issues of larger scale and affecting many people. For example:

> Today I am **dealing with** car repairs.

but

> Today, we are being **faced with** global warming, which is likely to wipe out a number of island nations.